# How to calculate capacitance when inductance in known?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance, frequency, inductance

Below is the diagram (sorry for bad accuracy) that shows how current changes with time in LC circuit. On X-axis we have time measured in milliseconds (ms) and on Y-axis current measured in milliamperes (mA). I know that inductance in this circuit is 20mH and I'm trying to calculate capacitance but however I try, my solution is wrong. Any advise on how to calculate capacitance? Thanks

[image: Current diagram]

Comment: Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your graph has a period of 30 milliseconds. Use that to find the frequency which can be expressed in terms of L and C.

Comment: Awesome now I finally got a solution of 1,1mF which is correct. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good answer (R.W.) and good work (Mr. Engineer).  You may want to write it as 1,100μF just to avoid chance of them assuming you mean 1,1 micro-Farad.  [Some folks](https://www.allacronyms.com/microfarad/abbreviated) use mF to mean μF.